# from google.cloud import language ImportError: No module named cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

Trying to use Google Sentiment Analysis. Here is the code I got from the Google tutorial.

"""Demonstrates how to make a simple call to the Natural Language API."""

```
import argparse

from google.cloud import language


def print_result(annotations):
    score = annotations.sentiment.score
    magnitude = annotations.sentiment.magnitude

    for index, sentence in enumerate(annotations.sentences):
        sentence_sentiment = sentence.sentiment.score
        print('Sentence {} has a sentiment score of {}'.format(
            index, sentence_sentiment))

    print('Overall Sentiment: score of {} with magnitude of {}'.format(
        score, magnitude))
    return 0

    print('Sentiment: score of {} with magnitude of {}'.format(
        score, magnitude))
    return 0


def analyze(movie_review_filename):
    """Run a sentiment analysis request on text within a passed filename."""
    language_client = language.Client()

    with open(movie_review_filename, 'r') as review_file:
        # Instantiates a plain text document.
        document = language_client.document_from_html(review_file.read())

        # Detects sentiment in the document.
        annotations = document.annotate_text(include_sentiment=True,
                                             include_syntax=False,
                                             include_entities=False)

        # Print the results
        print_result(annotations)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        'movie_review_filename',
        help='The filename of the movie review you\'d like to analyze.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    analyze(args.movie_review_filename)
```

Running the code I receive the following error:

from google.cloud import language
ImportError: No module named cloud

Comment: if you are using python 3+ try this `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud` this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the actual Google SDK Python module. The google-cloud library is pip install-able:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

See more [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/index.html).

Comment: I did upgrade google-cloud but still getting the same error - from google.cloud import language
ImportError: No module named cloud

Comment: More info: I am using Pycharm community edition on Mac - Google cloud is also appended in $PATH

Answer (score 0):

I used python -m pip install google-cloud instead and it worked! I had the same problem.My problem caused by pip.Pip was installing google-cloud in the wrong directory.