# Google sentiment analysis - ImportError: cannot import name language

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've had a python app running in google app engine for over a year.  I'm attempting to use the sentiment analysis.

```
from google.cloud import language
```

I get this error:

```
from google.cloud import language ImportError: cannot import name language.
```

It may be similar to this: [from google.cloud import language ImportError: No module named cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046035/from-google-cloud-import-language-importerror-no-module-named-cloud)

It seems like something has changed in terms of the google modules.  I also have these in my code:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
```

Thanks,

I'm digging into this more. I think I have my installation messed up when I updated the google cloud sdk.

It looks like I have two locations for the google modules:

```
C:\Users\username\lib\google
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\google\cloud\language
```

Here's some more information about my configuration using gcloud info.

```
Python Location: [C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

System PATH: [C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\sdk;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\username\scoop\apps\python\current\scripts;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\username\scoop\shims;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;]
Python PATH: [C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python27.zip;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\DLLs;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\plat-win;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\lib-tk;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
```

Comment: Did you vendor in the `google-cloud-language` in your app? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I believe you're correct.  I think I've messed up my install when I updated to the latest version of the cloud SDK.  Frankly, I've never understood where the google packages needed to be installed--I always just took the defaults from the installer.

Comment: Read that doc section carefully - vendoring in is done *inside* your app code (and it's uploaded to GAE together with your app code) - GAE treats it like your app code. Not much to do with your local python instalation, which SDK version or where it is installed.

Comment: Dan, thanks for your help and you work correct.  I needed to vendor it in. Ultimately I did this:
pip install -t lib/ --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install -t lib/ --upgrade google-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Dan was correct. I needed to vendor in the google-cloud-language my app.  I used the link that Dan posted: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library

Ultimately I did this from my project directory:

```
pip install -t lib/ --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install -t lib/ --upgrade google-cloud
```